# Twilio Programmable Chat - Access denied (code: 54007) for old chats

Tags: sdk, twilio, chat

We are using Twilio Programmable Chat on our project for 1 year. On the mobile side we use **twilio-chat v.6.0.0** SDK. On the backend side we use java library - **com.twilio.sdk:twilio:7.51.0**

### Problem

But a couple of days ago we started experiencing problems with authorization on the mobile side. Everything is ok when we create new chats and work with them.

But when we try to fetch messages for the old chats (created before that problems), we receive the following error `access forbidden for identity (status: 403, code: 54007)`

### What we tried

- We tried to upgrade/downgrade both mobile SDK and backend libraries.
- I've read the `code: 54007 documentation`. We have never configured any Sync services, possible they were introduced and not properly configured for the old chats?
- We have only one Sync service that was created (automatically) recently and **ACL enabled** flag is set to **false**.

[image: Twilio sync service settings]

Here is the structure of our access token:
[image: Access token structure]

My guess is that something has recently been changed with the permissions in the Chat API and the default config is not working for us.

I don't know exactly what it could be. Please, help.

Comment: I think you might have to ask [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) about this. If your app didn't change but the underlying behaviour did, then it could be a problem on the Twilio side. One note, while the date hasn't come yet, [Twilio Chat is being sunset in July 2022 in favour of Twilio Conversations and you should be looking to migrate](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/programmable-chat-end-of-life).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the official answer from Twillio Support that helped us:

> Recently the engineering team has effectively deployed some modifications over Programmable Chat; before this change, users would be able to see channel messages that they were not part of. With this update, users will receive error code 54007 for Chat if they try to read any channel that they are not a member of.

Answer (score 1):

In our case we got the same error when trying to fetch messages for a channel where the user is not a member of `Error: Access forbidden for identity (status: 403, code: 54007)`. This happened with Twilio SDK `twilio-chat` 6.0.0 and 4.1.0.

After we reviewed the "Roles and Permissions" section in the Twilio Console we noticed that the "service user" (which is the default user role for the chat user) did not have the permission "editChannelAttributes" activated, as compared to another sub account where fetching messages for unjoined channels was still possible.

Activating the permission "editChannelAttributes" for the service user and fetching messages seems to work again.

I'm not sure what the connection between this permission and fetching messages could be, but maybe this information is still helpful.